# using ios::ate over-write data

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++

My task is to write in a precise position into file.txt with C++
And because my file is static ( it will not be changed) I decided to count the position of curseur where I have to write. ( I know it isn't the best idea to di this)
This is my file and I have to write after '=' : 
[image]

It is clear that I want to over-write "null;"
But I don't understand why "int main" in the otehr line is also over-writed! Have a look to the following please to undersatnd my problem: 
[image]

My questions are the following:

- How Can I avoid this?
- Have you other idea to achieve the goal as described above ?

The is my attempt :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ofstream monFlux("client.txt",ios::in |  ios::ate);
   if(monFlux)    
{
    monFlux.seekp(61, ios::beg);
    int position = monFlux.tellp(); 

    monFlux<< "DECryptBlockWithPCRYPT(d);";


  }
    else
    {
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your idea will only work if you are replacing X characters with and equal number of characters.

Comment: Since you appear to be using Qt, take a look at `QString::replace` or Qt's regex library.

Comment: Sorry @Imran, I'm using C++
I'm not interested in the content of the file to modify. But chance, the file that I want to modifu contain QT code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it looks like you're opening an output stream for reading (`ios::in`) is that correct?

I don't think you can insert characters the way you describe.
Your approach is more like a human would do it in a text editor. The stream object on the other side just gives you access to the bytes on the disk. It has no "select and replace" text function.

I think this approach could work:

1. Open an input stream for reading the file and an output stream for writing one.
2. Stream the first N characters directly to the output stream.
3. Skip the "null" and insert your replacement string.
4. Stream the rest of the input file into the output stream.
5. On success, replace the original file with the new one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm agree that your approach can help me achieve my goal. (In fact,This solution typically applies when we we want to modify file) However, my situation is a little bit different because I know the content of file, I know the position where I have to modify and above all my file is static.
So, I don't know if it's more efficient.

Comment: It's not about efficiency. It's about replacing a string of length N with another of length M. To perform erase/insert operations you could read the whole file into a string/vector. But using streams will scale better for larger files.